# Page numbering like 1-1, 1-2 ect. (= ⟨chapter⟩-⟨page⟩)

Tags: page-numbering

How can I change the page numerbering to 1-1, 1-2, ect. The first number is the number of chapter, the second numner is the page in the chapter.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package [`chappg`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chappg) helps:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[auto]{chappg}
\pagenumbering{bychapter}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works well with standard classes. But It seems not to work for classes generated by sphinx. Just some more Infos.

Comment: Unfortunately this [breaks `\ifodd\thepage`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281173/430)...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler `\ifodd\thepage` should not be used, because `\thepage` can be quite different from an Arabic number, e.g. Roman numeral, letter. And `\thepage` can be wrong because of the asynchronous page routine. This can be solved by setting a page label and evaluating the page reference in the following LaTeX run (e.g. see package `zref`).

Comment: Good point. Fortunately KOMA has it's helpfull [`\ifthisipageisodd`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281175/430), too