# Numbering of a technical document

Tags: page-numbering

Goodmorning everyone,
I finished creating a technical Policy Paper, divided into parts, chapters, sections and subsections. I would like to create this page number:

## I Generalità

```
1 PENCA        I - 1
 1.1  CCCCC    I - 35
2. POLLA       I - 77
 2.1 EEEEE     I - 99
```

## III Tecnica

```
6 PENCA      III - 1
 6.1 HHHHH   III - 70
```

## VI Specifiche

```
 15 PUNCA        VI - 1
 15.1   LLLLL    VI - 37
```

Other information: in addition to the general index, the document also has a glossary, and a subject index; the document is based on the Book class and template "Orange Book" properly changed. It is possible to accomplish this? Thank's for your time.

## Update 31/03/2017

In strcuture.txt I've this:

```
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\tttext{\thepart~-- \arabic{page}}}
    \usepackage{chngcntr}
    \counterwithin{page}{part}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   PAGE HEADERS
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for header and footer configuration

    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}} % Chapter text font settings
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}} % Section text font settings
    \fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage} % Font setting for the page number in the header
    \fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark} % Print the nearest section name on the left side of odd pages
    \fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark} % Print the current chapter name on the right side of even pages
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} % Width of the rule under the header
    \addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt} % Increase the spacing around the header slightly
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Removes the rule in the footer
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}} % Style for when a plain pagestyle is specified

    % Removes the header from odd empty pages at the end of chapters
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
    \clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
    \hbox{}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
    \fi}
```

but, when I compile the code the only thing that happens is that the page numbering starts with the part page (which it's also what I want to) whereas page numbering on headers remains unchanged (of course restarts when it starts a new part). I hope I have been clear enough (sorry for my bad english).

## Update 06/04/2017

Sorry, I made a mistake. This is the result that I would need otherwise be rendered worthless the fact of having reset the numbers to each part. Anyone have any ideas?

## I Generalità

```
1 PENCA        I - 1
 1.1  CCCCC    I - 35
2. POLLA       I - 77
 2.1 EEEEE     I - 99
```

## III Tecnica

```
1 PENCA      III - 1
 1.1 HHHHH   III - 70
```

## VI Specifiche

```
 1 PUNCA        VI - 1
 1.1   LLLLL    VI - 37
```

Comment: The question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212505/page-numbering-like-1-1-1-2-ect-chapter-page might be roughly related.

Comment: Welcome! `\renewcommand\thepage{\thepart~-- \arabic{page}}` adds the part number. It seems that you want to reset the page number with every new part, so you also need something like `\usepackage{chngcntr}\counterwithin{page}{part}`. Depending on the document class that you use, you may now have to get rid of page number `0` on part pages, or maybe you want to start with 1. But this depends on the document class you use. If you need help, please provide a small document showing your setup.

Comment: I'm usign Arara to compile the source code:                                  % arara: lualatex: { synctex: yes }
% arara: biber
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: yes }
% arara: makeindex
% arara: lualatex: { synctex: yes }

Comment: The question is uncear to me. The numbering at the top and the numbering at the bottom do not match. Do you want to change the page numbers only? Is the section name part of the page number in your example? Please clarify and update the question.